# passing word list or pattern with tesseract image_to_string function

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ocr, opencv3.0, python-tesseract

I am trying to develop my first ocr project using python. I am also new to Python as well.

I am using OpenCV 3, with Python 3.6. I am trying to do OCR from a document.

Using OpenCV I have converted image to white bg and black text. It is reading most of the image fine. But to improve accuracy, I would like to pass list of pattern to an OCR engine.

Is this possible with pytesseract ?

for example I am trying to extract customer Id, and there only few customer ids possible, I can provide list of those to improve accuracy.

Same with date, I know it is always in a specific date format and if I can provide date format to improve accuracy ...

Any of these is possible? If yes can any one suggest me how ?

I have tried to search on stack overflow and google but could not find much help.

any guidance or direction will be helpful ...